# Mobile Devices Architecture - iOS, Android, WP7 and Disconnected Instances

Tags: android, ios, windows-phone-7

I am seeking some architecture advice within the mobile space.  I am wondering what people are today within their applications, say for the iOS, Android, WP7 devices, in terms of web services and instances for caching data when disconnected?

Many of our applications need to work offline due to having limited connectivity, so data storage/caching, synchronization, etc. is critical.

Any and all advice will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

If your apps need to work in a limited connectivity enviornment just store everything you need in a database, and have a synchronize option so the user can decide when he has connectivity to update everything or send data back to the server.

Another option would be to have the app monitor for connectivity, and when it is being used and a network is available have it automatically work in online mode and when no network is available in offline mode.

Depending on the level of "limited connectivity" I would just go for the full offline option and let the user synchronize. I develop apps that are used in many remote areas of south america and the full offline option is just better. I used to have issues with intermitent connectivity in border areas where the network would jump between available and unavailable and it made a mess in data transmition.

Answer (score 0):

I can't speak for iOS and Android, but for my WP7 app I store data offline in isolated storage. My app essentially works in disconnected mode so everything is stored offline and at certain events e.g. saving a task the app checks to see if it has a mobile connection and if so synchronizes with the back-end.